# PHP Array how to get header

Tags: php, arrays

HI all been trying to find solution for this array but I am not sure what is the term to use for this

I have this

```
$arraylist = 
Array ([0] => Array ([ID] => 123
                       [No] => 5 
                       [CLASS] => B)
       [1] => Array ([ID] => 456
                       [No] => 6 
                       [CLASS] => B)
)
```

`echo $arraylist[0]['ID']` gets 123
How can I get ID instead of its value

Comment: ... Why?  If you already have the string, then you can just print it.  Clearly your use case is something you're not showing us, so the replies probably won't be as helpful as you'd like.

Comment: The array is output of a read csv function. I want to make use of array to get the header.

Comment: Well, then xdazz has your answer.  array_keys() returns the keys in an array - or the header, as you put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($array[0]);
echo $keys[0];
```

Comment: And if anyone wants to do it with one statement, they could use `reset(array_keys($array[0]))`... not that I'd recommend it.

Comment: @arxanas you methods works but how to get NO and Class. I tried $array[2] I still get ID

Comment: @JonathanChan `reset` returns the first element of the array. I meant it only for the specific case shown. It's not very obvious what it does, anyways, and it also resets the internal array pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the array in the following manner:

```
//go over array 0 and array 1
foreach($arraylist as $arr){
  //go over ID, NO, CLASS
  foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    //here the first $key = 'ID' and first $val = 123
    // the second pass in the loop will have $key = 'No' and $val = 5
    // and so on.
    // so you can do whatever you want with it here
    //...
  }
}
```